# highcharts use variable as chart title

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts and js. Ihave a script running in HTML that draws a nice chart from a query that varies depending on some choices. I do not know what chart title is going to be until i do the query.

I have:
title: {
                    text: 'Round Trip Latency'
                },**strong text**

I want:

title: {
                text: $kpiName
            },

It does not work. How do i get the variable $kpiName to brin the value in the title?

Comment: What is $kpiName an html field or something else? This simple var works http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6c8Af/1/

Comment: You need to provide some more code, without knowing how your variables are set, when you are creating the chart, there is really now way to help you.

Comment: Example with title get from html field via jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6c8Af/2/ but tell something more...

Answer (score 0):

```
title: { text: [$kpiName] }
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

I think we're making this too complicated:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6c8Af/3/

You have:

```
var theTitle='Round Trip Latency'
```

So, in your chart code, all you have to do is:

```
title: {
        text: theTitle
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data before you construct your chart, you can just set the title in the configuration options. If you need to update the title of an existing chart, you can use the `setTitle` function.

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options); //create chart with initial data

//update data

chart1.setTitle('My New Title'); //update title
```

[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly answering the question, a common case might be that the title is put together using standard text and a variable. A template string serves this purpose perfectly:

```
title: {
    text: `Trend for ${this.state.selectedProduct.label}`
},
```